Does the FAA allow changing an aircraft's registered class?
For instance, if an aircraft is first registered as an airplane, can it later be changed to a glider or vice versa? How about a single converted to a multi?
(If you're wondering about why this could ever be a thing, imagine a homebuilt like a Sonex somehow converted into a Xenos.)

I am not sure, but I think once you get an airworthiness certificate it becomes very hard to change the class. But it is interesting to note that the FAA does not define a "glider" in the experimental category. A DER once told me that it comes down to how good a job the DER does of convincing the FSDO it should be one way or the other. Weird.
